# Write data in one row

Tags: php, sql

I use code with foreach. If I put the *insert* query into the foreach I have multiple rows with the same title.

> field1|field2
>
> title |content
>
> title |content2

How to write the title on one row and the content to be split with commas ?
**Edit**:

```
`foreach(...) {
 //INSERT INTO rss(title,content) VALUES ('$title','$content') 
}`
```

The title is the same ,but the content is different ,so how to build the query ,that the inserted row to be one and the content - split with commas.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean inserting more than one row in one query, you have to do something liket his :

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (col1, col2) VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6) -- etc
```

If you want to know how to generate this query, then you have to give us more information (which language? what have you tried so far?).

If you mean inserting more than one value in one column, it's is not a good idea as you break the first normal form. After your edit, it seems that this is what you are trying to do. It is not a good idea at all.

You have to create an extra table, for instance :

object (id_object, title)
content (id_content, id_object, content)

Where content.id_object references object.id_object, obviously. In this case, you add only one line per object in the object table. Then, every time you want to add extra content, you add a line in the content table.

**Edit**:
I repeat again: This is against the first normal form. Adding more than one value in a column is non evolutive, harder to manage and less efficient.

Comment: foreach(...) {
//INSERT INTO rss(`title`,`content`) VALUES ('$title','$content')
}

The title is the same ,but the content is different ,so how to build the query ,that the inserted row to be one and the content - split with commas.

Comment: @lam3r4370: please **update** your original question by editing it, and provide that information there, properly formatted and all. Here in comments, it's just a messy affair....

Comment: You would have to generate content first (in a loop) then do an INSERT query (not in a loop). But, as I said, that generally means you are breaking the 1NF.